# Save object with attributes for use in any file

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, save

I have a program performing a Monte Carlo Tree Search for chess. Using pickle to save the object (class instance) and loading it in some file would run the program (MCTS) the same as where I stored the object, from the start. In essence copying the program in stead of getting the object with values in the state it was before written to a .pkl file.

what i did:

`with open('chess_agent.pkl', 'rb') as data:
       agent = _pickle.load(data)`

It would just run the MCTS exactly the same as the file where I saved the object. I need to just get the instance with the values gotten in the file where I saved it.

how i saved:

`with open('chess_agent.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    _pickle.dump(Object, f)`

Since the object has so many values and objects connected with it and if the MCTS has been running for a while, it would be a shame to lose all progress if for any reason the program stops running.

Comment: "Using pickle to save the object (class instance) for use in any file did not work." What does "did not work" mean? What *exactly* did you try to do, and how, *exactly* did it not work? What does it mean to say you want to save an object "for use in any file?"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga When I loaded it, it would run the program from the start. In stead of just getting the instance with already assigned values

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Please provide more details about *exactly* what you are doing. What do you mean "when I loaded it"? What did you load, the pickle file? How? It ran *what program* from the start? What does that even mean? What program?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have edited the post with more details.

Comment: It is very unclear what your problem really is. You have not provided the code. Looks like you use pickle in some erroneous way - probably you do not save the actual data. More detailed answer hardly possible without details from you.